# How can I rearrange this pandas dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas

How can I convert the following type of dataframe into another dataframe with columns being the entries in the Target column

```
         Cq    Target   Sample Repeat
0  23.21562      NID1  Tgfb_48      4
1  23.31479    COL7A1  Tgfb_48      4
2  19.62652    COL1A2  Tgfb_48      4
3  20.99357  SERPINE1  Tgfb_48      4
4  25.26813       ELN  Tgfb_48      4
```

i.e.

```
                   NID1    COL7A1    COL1A2    SERPINE    ELN
[Sample, Repeat]    ... cq values here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['Sample','Repeat', 'Target'])['Cq'].unstack()
df.columns.name = None
print (df)
                  COL1A2    COL7A1       ELN      NID1  SERPINE1
Sample  Repeat                                                  
Tgfb_48 4       19.62652  23.31479  25.26813  23.21562  20.99357
```

Another possible solution, but here is aggregation if duplicates:

```
df = df.pivot_table(index=['Sample','Repeat'], columns='Target', values='Cq', aggfunc='np.mean)

print (df)
Target            COL1A2    COL7A1       ELN      NID1  SERPINE1
Sample  Repeat                                                  
Tgfb_48 4       19.62652  23.31479  25.26813  23.21562  20.99357
```